# how can I get the csv file object when using this code? I'm trying to add a function to convert a csv file to a json file

Tags: json, reactjs, csv

Now, the code I have right now is can select a local csv file and show the content by a table in the browser. What I'm trying to do right now is to after select a csv file, not only show the table in the browser, but also can convert this csv file to a json file in local. I know that we can't import fs in react. But I have no idea how to get the csv file object and to generate a json file.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';

function App() {

const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

// process CSV data
const processData = dataString => {
  const dataStringLines = dataString.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  const headers = dataStringLines[0].split(/,(?![^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);

  const list = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < dataStringLines.length; i++) {
    const row = dataStringLines[i].split(/,(?![^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);
    if (headers && row.length === headers.length) {
      const obj = {};
      for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        let d = row[j];
        if (d.length > 0) {
          if (d[0] === '"')
            d = d.substring(1, d.length - 1);
          if (d[d.length - 1] === '"')
            d = d.substring(d.length - 2, 1);
        }
        if (headers[j]) {
          obj[headers[j]] = d;
        }
    }

      // remove the blank rows
      if (Object.values(obj).filter(x => x).length > 0) {
          list.push(obj);
      }
    }
  }

// prepare columns list from headers
  const columns = headers.map(c => ({
    name: c,
    selector: c,
  }));

  setData(list);
  setColumns(columns);
}



// handle file upload

function handleFileUpload(e) {
const file = e.target.files[0];
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (evt) => {
  /* Parse data */
  const bstr = evt.target.result;
  const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });
  /* Get first worksheet */
  const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
  const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
  /* Convert array of arrays */
  const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(ws, { header: 1 });
  processData(data);
};
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}



return (
  <div>
    <input
      type="file"
      accept=".csv,.xlsx,.xls"
      onChange={handleFileUpload}
    />

    <DataTable
      pagination
      highlightOnHover
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
    />
  </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing Node.js (server/local) code, which can access the file system and has the `fs` module, with browser-side (client) code, which can't access the file system and doesn't have the `fs` module. You can't do that. You need to have a server piece that gets the information, and a client piece that queries the server for the information and renders it in the browser. (If you want to do a desktop application, look at Electron or similar, which make bundling these things together easy.)

Comment: Yeah, I just figured out that I can't use fs. But I'm still confused about how to get the csv file object and How to generate a json file. The idea I have right now is to write a function to get the csv file, and after parse, generate it to a json file. But, I'm confused that how to access the csv file and how to generate a json file by using react

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to use this function. But how can I get the csv file object and how to generate a json file is my question. I don't know whether this way works as well. Just an idea.

```
//var csv is the CSV file with headers
function csvJSON(csv){

var lines=csv.split("\n");

var result = [];

var headers=lines[0].split(",");

for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

  var obj = {};
  var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

  for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
      obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
  }

  result.push(obj);

}

//return result; //JavaScript object
return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}
```